# Form not being posted to controller asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

For some reason my form is refusing to post I have a controller with the method. I am using a base controller but its not overidden any of those methods just a few properties.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] 
public IActionResult Put(FileManagerViewModel fileManager) {
    FileClient client = new FileClient();
    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(fileManager.File.FileName);
    var remoteIpAddress = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
     var t = Task.Run(() =>
        client.UploadFileAsync(_context, "username", "password", fileManager.File.FileName, info.Extension.ToLower(), UserId.ToString(), remoteIpAddress.ToString()
      ));

        return View(fileManager);
}
```

Here is the form

```
@model MSFSAddons.Models.ViewModels.FileManagerViewModel

@{
   ViewData["Title"] = "Upload";
   Layout = "~/Themes/FrontEnd/_MyProfile.cshtml";
 }

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="FileManager" asp-action="Put" method="post">
<dl>
    <dt>
        <label asp-for="File"></label>
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <input asp-for="File" type="file">
        <span asp-validation-for="File"></span>
    </dd>
</dl>
 <input asp-page-handler="Upload" class="btn" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: Did you observe the Network trace in browser's developer tools? What does it show when you submit the form? Did you try changing the action name from `put` to something else?

Comment: `asp-page-handler` is meant to be used for Razor Pages, not MVC.

Comment: Remove asp-page-handler from declaration of submit button as suggested by @TiesonT.  and your form should post to controller. I tried your code in Visual Studio by removing asp-page-handler and it did post to controller.

Comment: @TiesonT. thanks was the answer